# How to disable / enable javascript file using plugins except AdBlock Plus

Tags: javascript, plugins

I need a handy plugins that will be able to disable and enable individual java script files for a website.

Say for example, My website is loading 5 java script files and one of these are causing a bug. I want to identify which java script is causing the problem.

I tried with AdBlock Plus. Actually I am looking for more handy tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Once a page is loaded, which means the scripts are loaded also, then there is no way of removing JavaScript from the page. Even if you removed the <script> tags, the JS would still run in memory. You'd have to stop the JS from being added to the page in the first place.

Comment: Any more details you could give us on where these JS references are coming from?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat - Yes I do agree with you. That is what AdBlock Plus is doing. That is, I choose  js file and put it in a block filter list and reload the page as js persist in them memory. Is there any handy tools that works same thing more flexible way ? ( I would prefer CSS Blocker UX style)

Comment: Okay, this isn't really a coding problem at all, then. You're just looking for a Chrome extension or something to block certain JS files.

Comment: If the JS files are coming from other extensions, you could change settings so that those extensions don't work in Incognito mode, and use Incognito mode to develop.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat - Yes this is not a coding problem at all. I am looking for a extension.Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this "NoScript" to block the java scripts.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript

Comment: I think, I am not looking for this. Thanks.